# Syntax error: Selector "button" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)

Tags: css, next.js, syntax-error, styling, css-modules

```
                <button onClick={() => resetBoard()}>
                    Reset Board
                </button>
```

I have encoutered this problem while importing external css as a module and my css file goes like this.....

```
button {
    background-color: #111827;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: .75rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    font-family: "Inter var";
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    padding: .75rem 1.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none #6B7280 solid;
    text-decoration-thickness: auto;
    transition-duration: .2s;
    transition-property: background-color, border-color,
        color, fill, stroke;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    width: auto;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #374151;
}

button:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: 2px solid transparent;
    outline-offset: 2px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .button {
        padding: .75rem 1.5rem;
    }
}

;
```

I want to apply css to the button tag imported as module from app.module.css file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `css module` you need to import and use it like this:

```
import styles from './app.module.css';
```

```
<button class={styles.button}>Click me</button>
```